# bootstrap three column positioning

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been trying to align three equal columns exactly in the center of a row with equal padding on both sides, inside a container-fluid. I am unable to position them at the center of the page. I have tried setting width to the container inside which those three columns are residing. but the layout keeps going one side and never gets aligned at the center.

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row yellow">
      <div class="col-lg-12 ">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-xxs-12 green text-center">
          test
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-xxs-12 green text-center">
          test
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-xxs-12 green text-center">
          test
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Attached is the output that I am recieving:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByPui.png)

As Shown here, the layout is aligned to right, I want it to align perfectly center with equal padding in between these columns.

It would be good to know how this can be achieved, I've been trying to get this one done for a while. your suggestions will definitely help in fixing this one.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is, that your layout is not summing to 12 columns..

`col-lg-3` + `col-lg-3` + `col-lg-3` are summing to 9 columns and in bootstraps grid-system you have 12 columns per row.

also there is no `col-xxs-**` class. *(lg = large; md = medium; sm = small; xs = extra small)*

this shoud do the trick:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row yellow">
    <div class="col-lg-12 ">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 green text-center">
        test
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 green text-center">
        test
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 green text-center">
        test
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Take a look at Bootrstaps Docs to learn more about the Grid-System: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: Hi @j.Sadi, thanks for the information and valuable input, this does allow to center the column, and also following gianni's comments i added an additional div into the column, it fixed this issue. Thanks guys :) Really appreciate the help

Comment: In this case you could add a div inside the columns with a padding or build an css class to add an offset to a "col-3" like i did here: https://www.bootply.com/UETIesdXaV

Answer (score 1):

As @Sadi says, the layout is made of 12 cols, so you shoold change your columns from  col-lg-3 to col-lg-4. Plus, you should apply your green to the inner container, otherwise you will have no padding:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row yellow">
   <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-xxs-12 text-center">
      <div class="green">
        test
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-xxs-12  text-center">
      <div class="green">
        test
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-xxs-12  text-center">
      <div class="green">
        test
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/giannidk/pen/ZymdOy

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Yes adding an additional div i side did fix my issue :)